# Windows 7 recommended for laptop with 1.7 ghz intel centrino n 1256 MB RAM?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, operating-systems

Will it be a good move to switch to windows 7 on my laptop with the following specifications...

1.7 ghz intel centrino processor
1256 MB RAM
Intel GMA 900 graphics support

or should i just stick with XP ???

Answer (score 1):

I would personally stick with XP.

At the end of the day, Windows 7 works well but as with Vista, my advise to XP users would be that there is little benefit to upgrade, especially on older hardware... If you have a spare licence, it may be worth taking a clone of your drive then install and see how you get on, but I wouldn't pay for an upgrade.

Comment: I'd argue there's significant benefit to upgrading on good hardware, but not here.

Comment: Windows Vista to 7, no arguments what so ever... Windows XP to 7... I think that if you have a "early Vista generation" computer that you downgraded to XP, I personally wouldn't - these PC's could barely run Vista... If you had a later one, I would... but +1, agree, on this hardware, I wouldn't

Comment: "these PC's could barely run Vista" - Well, this is not actually a consideration. I have a WinXP ThinkPad with a 1.8ghz CPU, 2GB ram... and it sputtered and stuttered on Vista, absolutely !requiring! ReadyBoost to run effectively. However, under Win7, it runs flawlessly!! 7 is a HHUUGGEE improvement over Vista, and even performance is VASTLY better.

Answer (score 1):

Moving to Windows 7 is always a good move from XP, and that machine will run it just fine. With the graphics taking 256MB, you will leave Windows 1GB of memory, which is plenty for 7. The processor is perfectly capable of running 7 as well.

The non-technical side of the decision is... are you going to be left in the past by continuing to use XP? As more companies start dropping support for XP, you will eventually start to fall further and further behind, and find it more difficult to find software for your machine (think of what a Win2000 or Windows Me user would go through now).